# How to define the type of a property based on one of the types in the same object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a React Component that takes up an object which returns the input component to be rendered. But right now there is no strict type checking and that is the problem. Check the example below:

```
const FieldRenderer = (fieldProps: any) => { // IMPLEMENTATION and TYPING here can be tweeked to add typing.
  // implementation here to be ignored
}

const fieldProps = {
  id: 'gender',
  label: 'Gender',
  type: 'dropdown',
  options: ['Male', 'Female']
}
<FieldRenderer fieldProps={fieldProps}/> // USAGE here can't be changed
```

But the problem here is that even if you pass something like **checked: true** (which is applicable to a checkbox) or **maxLength: 100** (which is for a textbox) the component won't show an error and I want all the other properties to be typed according to the **type** property in the object.

**Note: There is one problem though, the props are passed in the same way in the entire code base so I won't be able to change it, but need to have a type check in place.**

I need the following to be true

```
const FieldRenderer = (fieldProps: SomeTypehere) => {
  // implementation here to be ignored
}

const fieldProps = {
  id: 'gender',
  label: 'Gender',
  type: 'dropdown',
  checked: true
}
<FieldRenderer fieldProps={fieldProps}/> // Error here as dropdown doesn't need a checked property but also needs a options property
```

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: You're looking for discriminated union types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) for the type of `fieldProps` (in this case, using `type` as the discriminant):

```typescript
type CommonFieldRendererProps = {
    id: string;
    label: string;
};

type CheckboxFieldRendererProps = CommonFieldRendererProps & {
    type: "checkbox";
    checked: boolean;
};

type DropdownFieldRendererProps = CommonFieldRendererProps & {
    type: "dropdown";
    options: string[];
};

type FieldProps = 
    | CheckboxFieldRendererProps
    | DropdownFieldRendererProps
    // ...
    ;
type FieldRendererProps = {
    fieldProps:  FieldProps;
}

const FieldRenderer = (fieldProps: FieldRendererProps) => {
    // implementation here to be ignored
    return <div/>;
};
```

Notice that the type of `type` isn't `string`, it's the [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"checkbox"` for the checkbox props or `"dropdown"` for the dropdown props.

It works best when you're providing the props inline, because you don't have to provide an explicit type (or an `as const`):

```typescript
// Error as desired:
const bad = <FieldRenderer fieldProps={{
    id: "gender",
    label: "Gender",
    type: "dropdown",
    checked: true,
}}/>;

// Works
const good = <FieldRenderer fieldProps={{
    id: "gender",
    label: "Gender",
    type: "checkbox",
    checked: true,
}}/>;
```

...but you can also do it with explicit types:

```typescript
// Error as desired:
const badFieldPropsA: DropdownFieldRendererProps = {
    id: "gender",
    label: "Gender",
    type: "dropdown",
    checked: true, // <== Error here (would be on `type` if you used `CheckboxFieldRendererProps` instead)
};
const badA = <FieldRenderer fieldProps={badFieldPropsA}/>;

// Works
const goodFieldPropsA: CheckboxFieldRendererProps = {
    id: "gender",
    label: "Gender",
    type: "checkbox",
    checked: true,
};
const goodA = <FieldRenderer fieldProps={goodFieldPropsA}/>;
```

...or with `as const`:

```typescript
// Error as desired
const badFieldPropsB = {
    id: "gender",
    label: "Gender",
    type: "dropdown",
    checked: true,
} as const;
const badB = <FieldRenderer fieldProps={badFieldPropsB}/>;

// Works
const goodFieldPropsB = {
    id: "gender",
    label: "Gender",
    type: "checkbox",
    checked: true,
} as const;
const goodB = <FieldRenderer fieldProps={goodFieldPropsB}/>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=89&ssc=1&pln=72&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgGFcQIA7AMWCQBsATZVryREoABRxgAznAC8cAN7k4yuMF4AuOJJhRgrAOYUVcbigBGPTdt0GKAXwpVa9BgAskaANZmIAD048-EiCwsLiEFKyjMxsAXwCQiLhkQBkCkoqNHSa+GjuXj6+ZBnKeR6eSBpwPhDcqKz2jln0ACISvBAA7hxc8cGJYRLSckwgLD2BCaFiQ3BpisbNObztXazFxhEwwGySVjp6+gDaALqNlM1wcbzJw3AlcAA+jPneftdTSUMPz20RHd0Pv1prcHgB6MFwAB0MIeFEuQJCXwidwWKkwvRuQ00V0xt3slDQu3giIGUCiAAoMYFbppSSChgBKWQAPnSxghqnAdRAwRgKG2bDg7iIcBgEGq9GA+lY0EqDyIMAArlBWHAADy8YAANzBLPO5E5MmNcAAqpJDqpWNw9EhKJyAKJQHDklDSIQWogachE1jaaooXhRdX0kRwal8W4yeRo5RqHL6YFQfAAGgepgs3ByAHEk6mHksCCt-mt88Yyl5KpodEqkGm7HY9Y5OQB1aCeSQ+4lwfQQCBBuQhzGfYThvFDaOx1RVfCJpFllQZywEXPztOLZw5CtvIrrlTbqtiqC1+uN-X2yHGuTmy1IXxgG1oYDwZp7C9wJ0uuBuuAe4Be9Quz9eAzEDa5bgAQU0P4wABCY+iRQYUSiKd4wIOdEgXZQlyzFc8z3ZRC3wYtYNLAi4APKoazrOBOXVE1P2gYVQjgClOggJU+ElOAhQAA2aXjVEwOBqA4uAlUkSo4F4txykKUMkKkQS9G0VBeEZcgHCA-1QN4CDgwU8kIyxFFo108Chggs9m0hNsoA7bT4F7fsLJRKCXjk95hyTRTUQeNDZ3w9NzGXfBV0w8iiO3QosIo15D2o+sKF9f1nL0gzvMQozx1M+Q0tcqQrKbd8rzNC0DG-aQUpgQDDUhRjXXdJBPXlaqA14ArJAAIRQ-yZww4RYpwnMgo3bIi1WbpYso6tjzrTTKoo4lku7XSesHQyxxpCd5HMnKpC66z3zshy2vy-but64wAoG5NyOGvC1wLTcCGivxpviqi5vrRbqpW4Cez7Xh1o1TbjKjPKgc6w7iqAA)

---

In a comment you've asked:

> Can I use enum instead of string for type ?

Yes, you can, it works the same way. You can use anything for which TypeScript can see a district compile-time type, including enums.

```typescript
enum FieldType {
    CHECKBOX = "checkbox",
    DROPDOWN = "dropdown",
}

type CommonFieldRendererProps = {
    id: string;
    label: string;
};

type CheckboxFieldRendererProps = CommonFieldRendererProps & {
    type: FieldType.CHECKBOX;
    checked: boolean;
};

type DropdownFieldRendererProps = CommonFieldRendererProps & {
    type: FieldType.DROPDOWN;
    options: string[];
};
// ...
// Error as desired:
const bad = <FieldRenderer fieldProps={{
    id: "gender",
    label: "Gender",
    type: FieldType.DROPDOWN,
    checked: true,
}}/>;

// Works
const good = <FieldRenderer fieldProps={{
    id: "gender",
    label: "Gender",
    type: FieldType.CHECKBOX,
    checked: true,
}}/>;
// ...
// ... the other examples work the same as well...
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocpAOwFc8AxYJAGwBMAVATzCTgG9ycYXADCACQCiogNIAhAPIANOAF4CaABZI0AawBGEAB74ANEJEARBAoAKlhQHUAcmoJscYNhADu1M+QAvpQwPHyiuCAQ1EysbMjUbEhEULaeAM5ugiJwwGwAXHDpMFDA1ADmFDksKPqshcWlFRSBFOShvGLaeoZGsewJSSlpEGCZ6hEgUTHMAzRDySNjcABkAhbCHUiF-ZxhAHQS0vLKVSJaOrpIBXCGECyo1C1tW3CWnt5+u4PJixluk2m33mv1S-zW2REWx2sz2vH21jsDhcZ2EoxgwGi6QaJTK5QA2gBdZ4hMJwXZLcZwDZwAA+XUuvWBiVBlJp9Peo0+MziP2GGRpAHpBXB9mKaRRXsyFmDRlTIcJMLDKYVycqMi1KGgsfBpaC3AAKJVxFVq3kg-lygCUagAfOscsLcuAHiAaDAUBjonBtEQ4DAILc+MBytRoNcaUQYLQoNQ4AAeNjAABugttJPITtU2bgAFV0njctQWGUkJQnZIoDgoHAUJkkgWiAVyNrqMVbig2G543qUnBjexKap+Arcjd8OULQFqrV6gQAOJT8w5aFm9jceGI+xOZzL87dK43Eq0JDmQKBNNtJ2OaC6dItnVwcoQCBd9Q92F85L99Vy4ejvJCgnJcaRqOoWCAxcWSgacoTCGE4g3JBDikWRFCUPdhAuPRrkKY9TyCC903LEVs3UfNCyQIwwBLNBgHgLZsRIuBK2rWt6yQRtcIfNt4H0TsKQyABBQpOS8XweTmaC-jlLIaUAghJ2g2DhDAud8CgoYVP9eC1zhZCt2RXcaWww88KgE9TDgJ14xzVjoB9X44ANHwIFodggzgb0AAMtm83JMDgLg3LgWh0muOBvNEA8mU-C0ZLGfyymKVA2CtIIKFbdt+LYITu17b8BzYId+BywS5SEoirxFG8oDvHj22fV9yrGESGR6YwCtlZZ1AA8clK0zC4DUiCFxAlddN2JCUOOdChtM3D-QsgjWga+Amty-K4ukmsipKjaWvSSrL2Ysi8wLCp2LgLKYHyZj7JrOs4AbYAmzWjs2EOuQ5JyBTgOUoaRsg8a4N4BD1wOQyd3mg9Fvws8rpuzLHxy773y6n8TQyYcyt-MY5Cq5javqm6nxfT68fSNGHREP6BuSbSgbGgGaVXKaDiONDlBhy44eWhGnqR96Nupj9zR2zHB2x-gDspgmTqAA)

I used a string enum there, but it works with a number enum as well.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocpAOwFc8AxYJAGwBMAVATzCTgG9ycYXADCACQCiogNIAhAPIANADRCRAEQQKAChoUB1AHJqAvpRg8+o3CAjUmrNsmpskRKDpxgAznAC8AurCwGwAXHA+MFDA1ADmFCJwLCgARqwRUTHxFKYU5Ja8YgAWSGgA1qkQAB6O7C5uHl4QvgFitvZ1zjSN7s2tAGRBSYVIEV3cvAB0EtLyyokiaKUVSOFwVRAsqNS5+aNwGt5sEADuDsz1Pe593n6BNiB2F04NN553cEOCI1bjl5wrFMtLp9MZFsIWjBgPYfJlorE4gBtAC6ewsVjgXX69zgwTgAB8SmVKjUum8mnd8USji0TudyddKS0fPiAPRsuBTbn4igHRmud44to-ESYAE4iJYiV3XKUNCw+AC3pQNoACnFTkl0teTNuLIAlAEAHzDEQcuCgMDbEA0GAoaH2OClIhwGAQDZ8YBxajQNb4ogwWhQahwAA8bGAADc2cb0eQLf4k3AAKo+RGW6gsWJISgWyRQHCqlB+NzpojhcgK6hRDYoNhtMPK95wTXsHH+fiikLrfBxJn4NRJFLpFgRfAAcQHQ5Eo3+TkmSGB2j0hhM+OWJLWEWitCQZlMsfyFoM0HKrOrtbiEAgDcCTYBFPcrZlLM73ctvf7gqgg-xI4yAgpx-P9fl4ed2EXGYpFkRRVA3FZym3N0oD3A8jzzTkk0CNMMyQaprWANBgHgUY4UwuACyLOASzgMtgArMIq0VOs2GxO4AEEIlpMB6ReK4f31VpAg-UJx2-RpQJEACxyA6d8TnHVIKBEFV2MGdhE3VZ1l3fc4AtMNkyo6BnRuOA1VOCBaHYT04CdAADUZ7MtTA4C4Ky4FoHw1jgezREQqpakfPUPhZZzYiiVA2ANcg8mYmt4FSesOMbZsPBfLU7k7JK2NfXwOMPOMKNPKBz3iq8b1yzKWS44kKkCtKhNxUSv3k4c0kAyc2tnP4lMBaZZlg5QNLgLSkJ01D91iihL3ga9bxS+9GtVNs2A7fh5qq9tOMK48sOTXD4hovxZqYhNOWM4tSyQct-Vm1j2JZOQRXxMSCAk9wpOEGTx2AySRsUiYVJXMF1ySMbkN0sxjtGxUZpYnLnqW4LBJWvKfGy+tHt8ORduKs8LxYzbsZ8JGzR7cTuu+jrZK6kCAd6oGBpg+Z4PBxDIcm6HaNm+GErgTayYfXVUYy7a3w2yqSdxjCgA)

Comment: Can I use enum instead of string for type ?

Comment: @KishanVikani - Yes, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks this really helps. Btw there is one thing I noticed, If I don't pass in the props as inline way then it gives error as a mis match for **type** property. Can you suggest some way where I can do both inline props as well as assign a const obj to the props.    ERROR --->   

Type '{ id: string; label: string; type: FieldType; checked: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: FieldType.CHECKBOX; checked: boolean; }'.

Comment: Can you please help me with the final piece @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @KishanVikani - I don't think you can control which prop TypeScript complains about without using a helper function (`const props = someFunction(FieldType.CHECKBOX, {/*...*/});`), because it's not that the other field is wrong, it's that the other field and `type` are in conflict. It's possible with that helper function. Do you want to go that route?

Comment: Yes if that can help because the main problem is I can't change the usage as it's at a lot of places and I can only change at the place where I have my FieldRenderer @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @KishanVikani - You can't change the code where the props objects are defined? They're always going to be as shown in the question, objects with only an inferred type?

Comment: They can be passed as a const like in the question or even inline like the way you showed. Diff devs doing it differently. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @KishanVikani - Then I'm afraid I don't understand [your comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77557116/how-to-define-the-type-of-a-property-based-on-one-of-the-types-in-the-same-objec/77557241?noredirect=1#comment136735444_77557241), what usage is it you can't change? I'm only asking because I want to be sure to help solve the right problem. :-)

Comment: I have added comments in caps regarding to which is usage and implementation. I might be using wrong terminology maybe but I hope comments in the question clarify what you are asking. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @KishanVikani - No worries, it's probably me. Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAPe8N)? (Sorry, posted wrong link originally, that's the right one.)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to just give the props a union type:

```
type Props = {
    id: string;
    label: string;
    // other common properties
} & (
    {
        type: 'dropdown'
        options: string[]
    } | 
    {
        type: 'checkbox',
        checked: boolean
    } // more
)

const fieldProps: Props = { // Error
  id: 'gender',
  label: 'Gender',
  type: 'dropdown',
  checked: true
}
const fieldProps2: Props = {
  id: 'gender',
  label: 'Gender',
  type: 'dropdown',
  options: ['Male', 'Female']
}
const fieldProps3: Props = { // Error
  id: 'gender',
  label: 'Gender',
  type: 'checkbox',
}
const fieldProps4: Props = {
  id: 'gender',
  label: 'Gender',
  type: 'checkbox',
  checked: true
}
```